# How to obtain the name of the users App Store account without asking him?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to do this? There are a few users who continuously write bad reviews for all my apps immediately after every update. They're always pointing out competitor apps in an aggressive way. And they come from the countries where those competitors live. I am sure they ARE the competitors or hired by the competitors.

My app has built in twitter, facebook and please-rate-it-on-the-app-store buttons. I want to add them to a blacklist so when they get my next update, they won't be asked to do this bad things. I don't want to help them doing it, at least.

Maybe there's a way to programmatically get the iTunes account name which is stored on the device. Of course only if it can be done with public API. I just want to string-compare this at runtime against my blacklist and then simply not show those buttons for them.

Comment: I stopped reading at "without asking". Never do anything like this without permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not do this! I'm quite certain if this piece of code is detected you won't pass the review or your app will be pulled from the AppStore. 
Second, you cannot access the users app store name in your app.

Third, just "Report a concern" and provide a reasonable explanation.

[image]